# Zurich ZVV monthly/annual pass: how many trips per day?

Tags: public-transport, switzerland, zurich

I have just arrived to Zurich, Switzerland. I am considering to buy the [monthly or annual pass for the ZVV network](https://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/travelcards/networkpass.html). However I don't know how many trips per day can I take with one of these. Up to infinity?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what gave you the idea that a pass had a max amount of trips? Somewhere else it works that way?

Comment: @o0'. Maybe this sentence? "The monthly NetworkPass is good value for anyone making just three or four journeys per week." It is a bit confusing or even misleading in English; in German version the meaning is closer to "The monthly NetworkPass is *already* worth it for someone who makes just three or four journeys per week."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As many as you would like (and physically possible) within the zones chosen (some [night buses and trains](http://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets/night-supplement.html) may require additional supplement).

Like your own link says

> With a monthly travelcard you can travel as often as you like in the zones you have purchased.

Comment: +1. And (presuming you are buying a "110 card"): this covers trams, trains, at least one cable car, funicular railways, and ships (no Shipftax any more) provided they are within the zone. And if you want go e.g. to the airport, you buy a zone extension (which is cheaper than a normal ticket). Assuming you're commuting in Zurich (perhaps not right now) these are super-worthwhile. Especially as forgetting to buy a ticket can be a very expensive mistake.

Comment: @abligh Do they still perform spot checks?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Not sure what you mean by Spot Checks, but there are punctual checks where some ticket inspection people randomly board the bus/tram/train whatever and check everyone's ticket. AFAIK this was not done some time in the past due to the pandemic situation, but its back to normal now.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes, they perform spot checks. If you are asking whether they have restarted having stopped temporarily during the Coronavirus lockdown, yes they have restarted.